# 1980’s Sci-Fi novel about aliens who also had a prophecy about Jesus

Tags: story-identification, novel

1980’s sci-fi novel about an archeologist who was dying of lung cancer who meets the aliens who had a prophecy about Jesus on their planet. Turns out many alien planets had the same prophecy. Only Earth’s Jesus fulfilled it.

Comment: Something by Jack McDevitt, maybe?

Comment: Aliens: "Oh! You know Jesus too? That's great. We just loved him. We made him a king and gave him all kinds of glory and honor. What did you guys do?"

Comment: Makes me think of "The Man" by Ray Bradbury

Comment: https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/2008-11-24

Comment: [Calculating God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculating_God) by Robert J. Sawyer features an archaeologist (actually a palaeontologist) who is dying of lung cancer, and it has lots of discussion of religious issues with an alien. However it differs a lot from your description. It might be worth a look though.

Comment: @JohnRennie Also 20 years too late to be an 80s novel.

Comment: 1981 Phillip K. Dick *VALIS* is a novel about Gnosticism and aliens. I don’t think it had an archeologist though

Comment: @Andrew - thanks for the link! I couldn't remember where that gag was stolen from

Comment: No problem!   Glad to help